# how can I assing a value to List<ListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I assign a value to `List<ListItem>`

```
List<ListItem> ManagementDList;
ManagementDList.Add(0);
```

Comment: Please explain yourself better

Comment: `ManagementDList = something`?

Comment: `List<ListItem> ManagementDList = new List<ListItem>();` ? Then add items to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<ListItem> ManagementDList = new List<ListItem>();
 var item=new ListItem;
 ManagementDList.Add(item);
```